# phone microphone frequency range > 22kHz

Tags: android, audio, frequency, audio-recording, microphone

I was wondering, if there are any Android phones out there, capable of recording sound with a frequency higher than 20 kHz or even 22kHz.
According to Nquist you need twice the sampling rate for storing the data. I managed to record audio with a sampling rate of 192kHz on a Samsung S5 mini. But in audacity I can see the recorded audio data stops above 22kHz
[Audacity S5 Mini Audio Record wav screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JBNy0.png)

Any clue? Is the limitation the microphone?

Answer (score 0):

The only limitation of this would be the interface between the microphone and the system itself. Imagine the interface polls the microphone at a max of **44.1khz**, and you in turn poll the interface at **88.2khz**. Every other signal you receive is going to be a *duplicate* of the last one, because the interface hasn't changed since the last time you checked it.

Microphones don't have a maximum sample rate, because they are analog devices. The maximum comes from the device that checks its current state.